# R matrix get indices of two highest values

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (df) as below. I want to get column and row names for 2 lowest values in this matrix. There are multiple cells with the lowest value and I would like to get indices of all cells with the lowest value. From those indices I can choose randomly 2 indices.

In case of matrix df2, as only 1 cell has the lowest value and only 1 cell has has the second lowest value, I should get indices of those cells (value=0 and value=1)

What is an efficient way to do this? I tried to sort the matrix but it doesn't do what i am looking for :(

```
df<-matrix(data=c(3,7,5,0,1,0,0,0,0,8,0,9), ncol=2)
rownames(df)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")

 df2<-matrix(data=c(3,7,5,6,1,2,4,3,0,8,2,9), ncol=2)
    rownames(df)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
```

I tried something like this, but it is not efficient

```
minPoint<-which(df==min(df),arr.ind=T)
```

It will help me in case of the first matrix, but it wont return what i am expecting in case of the second matrix.

I would prefer a single code that works with both matrices

Comment: Your title says "highest values" but in your question you talk about "lowest values".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only `{base}` and based on your original code:

```
minPoint<-which(df <= sort(df)[2], arr.ind = T)
```

Rather than just getting the `min()`, using `sort()` will return a sorted vector, preserving duplication of minima. Checking for all values less than or equal to the second element should meet your requirement. In the case of `df` the first two elements are both 0, while in `df2` they are 0 and 1.

Output:

```
> which(df <= sort(df)[2], arr.ind = T)
  row col
d   4   1
f   6   1
a   1   2
b   2   2
c   3   2
e   5   2

> which(df2 <= sort(df2)[2], arr.ind = T)
       row col
[1,]   5   1
[2,]   3   2
```

Edit based on @Roland's comment: you can optimize for large matrices using `partial` sorting, eg:

```
minPoint<-which(df <= sort(df, partial = 2)[2], arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: it didnt return expected results in case of df2 matrix :(

Comment: You should use partial sorting: `df <= sort(df, partial = 2)[2]`. And of course you need to `sample` 2 rows from the result.

Comment: @user2543622 did you change `df` to `df2` in both cases, eg `which(df2<=sort(df2)[2], arr.ind = T)`? I made the mistake of not doing that when I first posted the outputs for this answer, and accidentally posted erroneous results (now edited).

Comment: @Roland, good point, thanks! Updated answer to include your syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 library(magrittr)

 func = function(mat)
 {
     sort(mat) %>%
     head(2) %>%
     lapply(function(u) which(mat==u, arr.ind=T)) %>%
     unique
 }

 #> func(df)
 #[[1]]
 #  row col
 #d   4   1
 #f   6   1
 #a   1   2
 #b   2   2
 #c   3   2
 #e   5   2

 #> func(df2)
 #[[1]]
 #     row col
 #[1,]   3   2
 #
 #[[2]]
 #     row col
 #[1,]   5   1
```

So that if you have one element in your list, you have a repeated minimum value.

Comment: First time i see the `magrittr` package. Very, very, very useful!