# select top n values (including%) for each column of dataframe and show their relative values of a certain column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot-table

This is my data

```
df <- data.frame(
    city = c("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid", "Venice", "Bern"),
    Spring = c(10, 3, 6, 9, 23, 8),
    Summer = c(1, 5, 6, 4, 30, 12),
    Fall = c(22, 24, 15, 4, 12, 8),
    Winter = c(0, 12, 4, 22, 7, 9),
    
    check.names=F
) %>%
    janitor::adorn_totals(c("row")) %>%
    janitor::adorn_percentages("col") %>%
    janitor::adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
    janitor::adorn_ns(position = "front")
```

[image]

I want to create data frame below, which is simply showing what the two top mostly visited cities at each season are.

[image]

This is what I tried

```
  semi_output <- df %>%
  filter(city != 'Total')%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -city) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  slice_max(value, n = 2, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  unite(city, c("city", "value"), sep = '-')
```

[image]

It seems like it works in terms of capturing the top 2 cities for each season (which is weird! These cells are not numbers they contain characters such as "(" and "%" is this reliable always?How is R able to sort them?)

But my main question now is how to convert this format to what I showed above as my desired output?

Comment: When you add percentages, you are converting the data from numeric (which sorts in numerical order) to character (which sorts in alphabetical order). If you want to do sorting and calculations and filtering, do that first and only add percentages and other formatting options at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use simpler functions if we do the calculations first and the formatting / display options at the end.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-city) %>%
  mutate(pct = value / sum(value), .by = name) %>%
  slice_max(value, n = 2, by = name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = name) %>%
  transmute(row, name, label = paste0(city, " (", sprintf("%0.2f%%", pct*100), ")")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = label)
```

Result

```
#A tibble: 2 × 5
    row Spring          Summer          Fall            Winter         
  <int> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
1     1 Venice (38.98%) Venice (51.72%) Paris (28.24%)  Madrid (40.74%)
2     2 London (16.95%) Bern (20.69%)   London (25.88%) Paris (22.22%)
```

Comment: thank you! way easier now. and .by argument inside dplyr functions was new to me!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to start from *after* `adorn_` then you could do:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  filter(city != "Total") |>
  pivot_longer(cols = Spring:Winter, values_transform = readr::parse_number, names_to = "season") |>
  slice_max(value, n = 2, by = season) |> 
  pmap_dfr(\(city, season, ...) tibble(!!season := paste0(city, "-", df[df$city == city, season]))) |>
  map_dfr(na.omit)
```

If you start from *before* `adorn_` you could do:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(across(Spring:Winter, list(p = ~ sprintf("(%.2f%%)", .x / sum(.x) * 100)))) |>
  rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), Spring:Winter) |>
  pivot_longer(contains("_"), names_sep = "_", names_to = c("season", ".value")) |>
  slice_max(value, n = 2, by = season) |>
  mutate(cell = paste0(city, "-", value, " ", p), season, .keep = "none") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = cell, values_fn = list) |>
  unnest_longer(everything())
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are likely cleaner ways using external packages, adding in base R approach that creates a little helper function to give the indices of the top two positions (minus the `Total` row), then index off of that using `lapply`.

The helper function `sortfun` uses `regmatches`, `gregexpr`, and `gsub` to [extract the numeric values between the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735503/extract-numbers-between-brackets-within-a-string), then subsequently [gets the indexes of the two highest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414177/r-matrix-get-indices-of-two-highest-values).

```
sortfun <- function(x){ 
  ords <- (as.numeric(gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", 
                                regmatches(gsub("\\%", "", x), 
                                           gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", x)))))
  which(ords >= sort(ords)[length(ords) - 1], arr.ind = TRUE)
}

orders <- lapply(df[-grep("Total", df$city), -1], sortfun)

# $Spring
# [1] 1 5
#
# $Summer
# [1] 5 6
#
# $Fall
# [1] 1 2
#
# $Winter
# [1] 2 4

nnames <- names(orders)
top2 <- lapply(seq_len(length(orders)), \(x) 
               paste(df$city[rev(orders[[x]])], 
                     df[rev(orders[[x]]), nnames[x]], sep = "-"))

final_tab <- setNames(do.call(data.frame, top2), nnames)

#                Spring              Summer                Fall              Winter
# 1 Venice-23  (38.98%)   Bern-12  (20.69%)  Paris-24  (28.24%) Madrid-22  (40.74%)
# 2 London-10  (16.95%) Venice-30  (51.72%) London-22  (25.88%)  Paris-12  (22.22%)
```